# How to sort multidimensional array by highest value using php usort?

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array, usort

How can i sort my multidimensional array based on inner array value descending?

My array is:

```
array [
  0 => array [
    "name_TH" => "test"
    "currnetMonth" => 200.0
  ]
  1 => array [
    "name_TH" => "test2"
    "currnetMonth" => 3000.0
  ]
  2 => array [
    "name_TH" => "test3"
    "currnetMonth" => 1455.0
  ]
]
```

I try to do something like but still not sure how it's work with dimensional array

```
usort($data, function ($a, $b) {
  return dd($b);
});
```

Comment: Check documentation for usort(): http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php
You have to provide valid comparing function for  usort function. Check the example there. Have no idea what dd() function is?!!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$a` and `$b` in `usort()` is first level index of array that is also array. You should get `currnetMonth` index of `$a` or `$b` in function

```
usort($arr, function ($a, $b) {
    if ($b["currnetMonth"] == $a["currnetMonth"]) return 0;
    return $b["currnetMonth"] < $a["currnetMonth"] ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Or in write condition in one line

```
usort($arr, function ($a, $b) {
    return ($b["currnetMonth"] == $a["currnetMonth"]) ? 0 : ($b["currnetMonth"] < $a["currnetMonth"]) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Check result in [demo](https://ideone.com/z8wdEE)